# _iVar and @property?

Tags: ios, properties, synthesize

I see someone writes codes like this

```
@interface SomeClass:<NSObject>{
       NSString * _iVar;
```

}

```
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *iVar;
```

and in implement file

```
@synthesize iVar = _iVar;
```

But I always like write codes like this:

```
@interface SomeClass:<NSObject>
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *iVar;
```

and in implement file

```
@synthesize iVar = _iVar;
```

They all works fine, and I can use an instance someClass to get iVar "someClass.ivar".I just know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You now don't even have to synthesize the iVars anymore.  The latest Xcode will automatically create a backing instance variable for each property, with the property name prefixed with an underscore.

Comment: Does that mean if I don't write {
       NSString * _iVar;
} xcode will write it for me and now I even don't need write @synthesize  any more?

Comment: Right, it's taken care of for you.  The exception is if you want a different iVar name than the default.

Answer (score 0):

In Objective-C when you are using anything via "." (dot syntax), it is accessing property. You have declared and synthesize a property with name iVar, so you can access it with someClass.iVar.

When you are declaring a property, a variable is automatically created with it. So, even if you do not create a variable, it will be there.

To avoid ambiguity, people are creating properties and iVar with different names. So, they can identify if the variable is being used or a    property is being used. In that case people let the compiler know that a particular variable is associated with a property by low way:

```
@synthesize iVar = _iVar;
```

If you want access variable directly outside the class instead of property, you should use "->" (arrow syntax).

Comment: I got it,you mean xcode will create one for me if I don'k write  { NSString * _iVar; } in interface file.Thank you very much for your answer!